# Reverse Git Push to FortRabbit

Tags: git, fortrabbit

I've pushed my most recent commit to fortrabbit, the .gitignore didn't work and now my database has been overwritten, is there a way to rollback the push?

Comment: Are you saying your DB is in your git repo?

Comment: Maybe you're using SQLite ? You should probably contact them to get some help